# How can I connect over SSL using Socket.io?

Tags: ssl, socket.io

I am just learning socket.io, websockets, node.js, etc. I am using the "Minimal working example" available here: https://socket.io/docs/.

My index.js file:

```
const content = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');

const httpServer = require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  // serve the index.html file
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(content));
  res.end(content);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);

io.on('connect', socket => {
  console.log('connect');
});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('go to http://localhost:3000');
});
```

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Minimal working example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="events"></ul>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const $events = document.getElementById('events');

        const newItem = (content) => {
          const item = document.createElement('li');
          item.innerText = content;
          return item;
        };

        const socket = io();

        socket.on('connect', () => {
          $events.appendChild(newItem('connect'));
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I SSH'd in using Putty and started the node server `$ node index.js`

The script will not connect, so I changed "http" to "https".

Index.js runs fine from Putty. Then I bring up https://www.example.com:3000/testbin/sockets and I get an error about security:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to www.example.com:3000. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).

Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

I believe the problem is that I am not connecting securely here. I thought changing the sample code given at the socket.io documentation from http to https would do the trick, but it did not. It did not throw an error in SSH, so I know https exists...

Can anyone please advise me how to connect using Socket.io when the website requires SSL?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think you need to create a https server along with your SSL certificates, something like this https = require('https'),
fs = require('fs'),
var pkey = fs.readFileSync(/PATH_TO/key_live.pem),
 pcert = fs.readFileSync(/PATH_TO/cert_live.pem),
    options = {
        key: pkey,
        cert: pcert,
        passphrase: 'MY_CERT_PASS_PHRASE'
    }

sslSrv = new https.createServer(options).listen(port);

Comment: Thank you very much! Good suggestion. I am not sure what directory they were be located in, so I opened a ticket with my hosting service to find out the path. I am surprised this is necessary, really.